# React Native: How to access a variable from parent component in child component?

Tags: javascript, react-native, socket.io

i am trying to pass my newsocket variable from my MessagesScreen.js to my ChatScreen.js.

I have been stuck on this point for a while and would appreciate any help possible. What i am trying to achieve is that only one connection gets emitted which i can listen to events on both screen.

The connection is now opened on the messagesScreen. My problem now is  if user 1 is on the allmessages screen and user 2 is inside the chat. And user 2 sends user 1 a message, user 1's screen does not automatically update with the last message for the conversation the message was sent to, I need to either scroll to refresh or navigate from one page to the other in order for it to appear.

Here is my code:

PARENT --> messagesScreen.js

```
function MessagesScreen({navigation}) {
const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
const { user } = useAuth();
const [socket, setSocket] = useState(null);

const loadposts = async () => {
const response = await messagesApi.getMessages();// here i am loading all the conversation this user has
setPosts(response.data)
};

useEffect(() => {

newsocket = sockets(user.id); // newsocket is what i am trying to pass to child component
setSocket(newsocket);

loadPosts()

newsocket.on("send_message", (msg) => {
  console.log("messages:", msg);
})

}, []);

return (
<FlatList
    data={posts}
    keyExtractor={(post) => post.id.toString()}
    renderItem={({ item,index }) => (
      <MessagesList
      title={item.Post.title}
        subTitle={item.Messages[0].message}
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate(
                routes.CHAT,{message:item,index,newsocket:socket})}
      />
    )}
  />
)
```

CHILD ---> chatScreen.js

```
function ChatScreen({route,navigation,socket}) {  
const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);
const { user } = useAuth();

  const index = route.params.index;
  const message = route.params.message;
  const newsocket = route.params.newsocket;

  const loadListings = async () => {
  const response = await messagesApi.getConversation(message.id);// here i am loading the messages in that specific conversation
  setMessages(response.data.Messages)
  };

 useEffect(() => {
 loadListings()
 newsocket.emit('subscribe', message.id);

 newsocket.on("send_message", (msg) => {
    console.log("this is the chat messages:", msg);
    setMessages(messages => [msg, ...messages]);
  });
  }, []);

 const onSend = (ConversationId,senderId,receiverId,message) => {

const to = (user.id===route.params.message.user1? 
route.params.message.user2:route.params.message.user1)

socket.emit('message', { to: to, from: user.id, message,ConversationId});

messagesApi.sendMessage({ConversationId,senderId,receiverId,message});
};

return(
 <FlatList
    inverted
    data={messages}
    keyExtractor={(item,index)=>index.toString()}
    extraData={messages} // add this    
    renderItem={({item,index})=>(
        <MessageBubble
        text={item.message}
        mine={item.senderId !== user.id}
        />
    )}
    />
)
```

socket.js

```
import io from 'socket.io-client';

const newsocket = (user) => {
let newsocket = io.connect("http://192.168.1.107:9000")

newsocket.on('connect', msg => {
console.log(`waiting for user: ${user} to join a conversation`)
});

newsocket.emit('waiting', user);

return newsocket;
}

export default newsocket;
```

Comment: You can go with Redux as well. Please go through this https://redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started

Comment: @Swanand Hi, thank you for getting back to me. Is it possible to achieve this without redux?

Comment: Please format the code for easier reading.

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this differently.

1. You can create your socket connection as a shared service in a separate module and simply import that into the relevant components you need. In this shared module you handle connecting/disconnecting and return an existing connection or create a new connection to return.

Quick rough:

```
// socket-server.ts
import io from 'socket.io-client';

let socket: SocketIOClient.Socket = null;

export const getSocketServer = (): Promise<SocketIOClient.Socket> => {
    return new Promise<SocketIOClient.Socket>(resolve => {
        if (socket) {
            console.info(`returning existing socket: ${socket.id}`);

            return resolve(socket);
        }

        socket = io('http://localhost:4000', {
            autoConnect: false,
        });

        socket.on('connect_error', (err) => {
            console.error(err);
        })

        socket.on('connect', () => {
            console.info(`creating new socket: ${socket.id}`);

            return resolve(socket);
        });

        socket.open();
    })
}

// then in your relevant modules
// module-a.ts
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {getSocketServer} from './../components/socket-server';

const Component = () => {
    useEffect(() => {
        const connect = async () => {
            const socket = await getSocketServer();

            socket.on('hello', (message) => {
                console.info('hello from module A', message);
            });
        }
        connect();
    }, []);

    return (
        <>
            <h2>Module A</h2>
        </>
    )
}

export default Component;
```

2. You could maybe also look at creating a [Context Provider](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) and share the socket with relevant modules as needed.

> Context provides a way to pass data through the component tree without
> having to pass props down manually at every level.

Comment: Hi Samuel Thank you for getting back to me. Isn't this what i am doing at the top in socket.js? Where i am creating the connection in socket.js and importing socket.js into the parent component. i have a quick question: in my `useEffect` in my parent compoent, when i set `setSocket(newsocket)`; if i tried accessing the socket state variable (ie.`socket`) after isn't it also supposed to equal `newsocket`?

Comment: You want to be able to share this socket service throughout the application - think of it like a DB connection. This is a typical service pattern. Anytime state changes or the component re-renders your variable: `var socket` is being defined again. If you don't fully understand how state changes and how components re-render, then take a moment to read up. PS - in `socket.js` you should rather ensure you connect before you start emitting. [useEffect](https://blog.logrocket.com/guide-to-react-useeffect-hook/)     [useEffect](https://iqkui.com/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/)

Comment: Hi Samuel, i formatted my code to make it easier and have updated it with my recent changes. Currently with the code above when i reload my app and go to the parent screen then connection is established if i leave this screen to go to any other screen then back the connection is still open it does not close then open again. Also, the socket listener in my allMessages screen is currently listening to the same event as on the chat Screen (send_message) does this mean my socket its working?

Comment: Yes, it should not close and open if you are navigating on the client. If you do want it to close, then call a close method on the shared service. Yes, all components that register listeners will receive the messages - this allows you to handle them differently in relevant modules.

Answer (score -1):

On the `MessagesScreen` screen you are passing the `SOCKET` function and not the variable it self .  i think you do not need the function . you directly pass the variable and access in `chatScreen` screen .

**MessagesScreen.js**

```
routes.CHAT,{message:item,index,updateView, newsocket})}
```

**chatScreen.js**

```
const newsocket = route.params.newsocket;
 ....

newsocket.emit('subscribe', message.id);  // call like this
```

Comment: Hi Mehran thank you for getting back to me. In MessagesScreen inside useEffect when i `console.log(newsocket)` i get my socket object BUT in chatScreen when i `console.log(newsocket)` i get `undefined`.